# How to Convert 24-byte byte array to 16-byte byte array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, byte

I have a byte array `b_a`. `len(b_a)` returns 24. But I want to make `b_a`'s length 16 without data loss. Is there any way of that?

Comment: Do you just want to remove the last 8 bytes? What type is the array exactly (`list`, `bytes`, ...)?

Comment: I don't want data loss. Is there any way to do this? It's type is `bytearray`. I converted it from `bytes`.

Comment: If you are converting 24 bytes to 16 bytes, there **must** be data loss, right? 8 bytes need to be removed, the only question is which ones.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how do you want to achieve that. If its length is 24, then there is 24 elements in it, obviously. If you want to make it 16, you will have to remove 8 elements.

You can do this by:

Slicing:

```
b_a = b_a[:16]
```

or

```
b_a = b_a[8:]
```

or any combination:

```
b_a = b_a[2:18]
```

Or you could `.pop()` items:

```
b_a.pop(). # do this 8 times
```

or

```
b_a.pop(some_index). # do this 8 times
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also part bytearray into slices like strings. So `len(mybytearray[0:16])`

But this will not work well. Because in different encoding sets (utf-8, ascii...), characters occupy different amounts of number.
That's why we need to know what you encoded your bytearray with.

It may still work for you:

```
mybyte = bytearray("uğurcanveözlemkardeşler", 'utf-8')
mybyte16 = mybyte[0:16]
mybyte16
```